# Google Apps Script: getFileById Error "Exception: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

My script that grabs a url from a Google Sheet and attaches to an email has worked without issues on a test copy of a spreadsheet, but is throwing an error when run on the original.

> Exception: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and
> try again

Below is a trimmed down version of the script

```
function wireInfoEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Current");
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lc = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange(3,1,lr-2,lc);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(2,1,1,lc).getValues();
  var atchUrlColName = "Instructions_Link";
  var atchUrlCol = headers[0].indexOf(atchUrlColName);
  var propAdColName = "Address";
  var propAdCol = headers[0].indexOf(propAdColName);
  var borrowRepColName = "Borrower_Rep";
  var borrowRepCol = headers[0].indexOf(borrowRepColName);
  var wiColName = "Sent_WI's";
  var wiCol = headers[0].indexOf(wiColName);

  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "MST", "M/d/yy");

  for (var i = 0; i < lr-3; i++) {
    if (values[i][wiCol] == "" && values[i][propAdCol] !== "") {
      //Get attachment, throw an error if there is no URL
      var fileUrl = values[i][atchUrlCol];
      var fileId = fileUrl.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
      try {
        var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
        var fileAttachment = file.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
      }
      catch(err) {
        Logger.log("Message : " + err.message + " - Stacktrace: " + err.stack);
        throw "No attachment linked on row " + (i + 3);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the Debugger, `file` shows `undefined`. I verified that I have permission to open the URL in a browser. I also tried replacing

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
```

with the actual file id as a string

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("AAAAAAAA");
```

and I still get the same error.

Edit: I added a Logger to the catch and got the following.

> 6:32:58 PM    Info    Message : We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. - Stacktrace: Exception: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.
> at wireInfoEmail (Wire Instructions Email:54:29)
> at **GS_INTERNAL_top_function_call**.gs:1:8

Comment: I would suspect your regular expression. Here are the word characters for `\w` == [0-9A-Za-z_] [reference](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/main/doc/syntax.txt) There's probably some inconsistency in the data that you didn't expect originally.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it looks like I need to clarify what I said at the end which is that I still get the error even when I use the file ID as a string instead of the variable.

Comment: Try the script in a new script project.

Comment: @enano2054 also add the details of the error: like: `catch (err) { Logger.log("Message : " + err.message + " - Stacktrace: " + err.stack); }`.

Comment: @TheMaster It does work from a new project. The owner of the spreadsheet has a lot of other spreadsheets and Google forms all linked to the original so working from the copy would be a project. Is that the only option?

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes I'm updating the original question to show those details. Thank you.

Comment: Try waiting.  You could create a new ss bound project as well

Comment: @TheMaster It has been a few days. How long do you suggest we wait? Is it possible to replace the currently bound script with another?

Comment: You could have two bound scripts and then delete the old one. You need to re-add the triggers though

Comment: @TheMaster I finally figured out how to add a second project to the container and it is working, but I can't figure out how to delete the original. Thank you!

Comment: In sheets, you'd go to Tools>Script editor>select the bound script you want to trash and then `i` info button on top left > trash button on right.

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks again for your responses, that trash icon is greyed out and unclickable. I'll live with the extra for now

Comment: Hmmm.. Are you the owner of the spreadsheet?

Comment: @TheMaster I am not but the owner just left town so I'll have him try when he is back. Thank you for your help, this took care of the biggest issue.